# Angular.js. Two-way data binding breaks when using services

Tags: angularjs

The problem is that SecondName attribute is not updating when I input text in the field.

please look at this code at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HEdJF/253/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">


      <div>
         <input type="text" ng-model="Data.FirstName"><!-- Input entered here -->
         <br>FirstName is : <strong>{{Data.FirstName}}</strong><!-- Successfully updates here -->
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl as Second">
            SecondName: {{Second.Data.SecondName}}<!-- How do I automatically updated it here? -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('Data', function(){
    var obj;
    return obj = { FirstName: '54',
                  SecondName: '22',
                           f: function(){
                              obj.FirstName = '1';
                              obj.SecondName = obj.FirstName;
                           }
                 };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
  Data.f();
  $scope.Data = Data;
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function( Data ){
  Second = this;
  Second.Data = Data;
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fkLg93nc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to work like you think it should. This line:

```
obj.SecondName = obj.FirstName;
```

creates a new property `SecondName` equal by value to the `FirstName`. However since both properties are primitive types (`String`) there is no connection between them. In other words `obj.SecondName` does **not** reference `obj.FirstName`.

You have two options.

**Option 1. (bad)** Set up additional watcher on `FirstName` change, and once that happens update `SecondName` respectively

```
$scope.$watch('Data.FirstName', function() { Data.SecondName = Data.FirstName; });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HEdJF/254/

**Option 2.** Don't introduce additional watchers and change your architecture. For example, use `FirstName` in the second controller too, since they are supposed to be equal.

http://jsfiddle.net/HEdJF/255/

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work! I have to use 'bad' option, because actually in my code the 'SecondName' property changes and not equals to the 'FirstName'.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue because of your nested scopes. Take a look at this website for a clear explanation: http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/. There's a few different solutions to solve your problem under the Nested Scopes section.

Comment: Changing the code to make it without nested scopes doesn't help. Anyways thanks for the article, it is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the First Controller is just changing the value of `Data.FirstName` object, hence the changes are not reflecting on your second controller because the value of SecondName does not change after it is initialized in the first controller. So you have to set your `Data.SecondName` 
in your data as well.

Alternatively, you can do this.

```
 <div>
         <input type="text" ng-model="Data.FirstName"><!-- Input entered here -->
         <br>FirstName is : <strong>{{Data.SecondName=Data.FirstName}}</strong><!-- Successfully updates here -->
      </div>
```

You can also use directives to achieve this functionality, but I guess you are just looking for the above solution.

Cheers!